# Ember access model directly without {{ model.prop }}

Tags: ember.js, model, controller

http://jsbin.com/dikemagi/2/edit

When I have no controller, using `{{name}}` in template works fine to access the name property, but when I create a controller, model property is now not available via `{{name}}` and has to be accessed via `{{model.name}}`.

Is there a way to access it the same way as before creating a controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your controller type as an Object Controller, as follows:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```